# AVAudioPlayer doesn't work in shared class swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I w call a method from a singleton class that allows to play sound from other classes but the player doesn't work, I tried what is mentioned in posts dealing with the same problem but it didn't work for me, here is my code :

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
var soundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class MySingleton: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
var timer = NSTimer()

   class var sharedSingleton: MySingleton {
    struct Static {
        static var onceTocken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance : MySingleton? = nil
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceTocken) {
        Static.instance = MySingleton()
    }
    return Static.instance!
        }
func callTimer () {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.6, target: self, selector: "repeatedSound", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func repeatedSound() {

    var repeatedSoundUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:    NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(prayerRepitationList[selectedCellInIndex], ofType: "mp3")!)

    soundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: repeatedSoundUrl, error: nil)
    println("repeated url is \(repeatedSoundUrl)")
    soundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    soundPlayer.delegate = self
    soundPlayer.play()


}
}
```

I tried `var player : AVAudioPlayer! = nil  : AVAudioPlayer! = nil` but not working, 
How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a colon ":" to the end of the selector name when creating the timer since that method specifies a parameter. It looks like this:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.6, target: self, selector: "repeatedSound:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

}

And, since the method that the timer calls receives an argument of the timer itself, it must be specified like this:

```
func repeatedSound(timer: NSTimer) {
  // your other code goes here
}
```

I did not try your code, but that should help.